# Bottom up vs top down merge sort

Tags: merge, language-agnostic, mergesort

The way I've learned or seen merge sort implemented has always been the top-down recursive approach which requires O(n) extra memory.

It seems with the bottom-up approach, you can do this with constant memory. The merge operation is identical to the top-down approach. So it seems to me that bottom up is superior to top down.

Why is the top-down approach more commonly used and taught?

Comment: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top down is more commonly taught, but bottom up or more accurately, a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort is more commonly used in libraries.

The space overhead for the second buffer is the same for both a conventional top down and bottom up merge sort O(n). The stack overhead for top down is O(log2(n)).

There are variations of merge sort that use a smaller second buffer or no second buffer.

Comment: Why is bottom up more commonly used?

Comment: @roulette01 - Partially a legacy issue, early versions of merge sort were implemented on systems without a stack. I don't know when top down merge sort was invented or why. A natural merge sort that looks for existing sorted runs of data is inherently bottom up. [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is similar, but uses a stack to keep track of runs in a manner than maintains stability (keeping equal elements in their original order). Bottom up is slightly faster than top down, but the difference is so small that I doubt it is a factor.

Comment: Ah. I see. For some reason, I thought bottom-up was O(1) space, but clearly it's still O(n) because of the merge operation as you alluded to (although space complexity is still slightly better because you no longer accumulate a recursion stack). I heard that there's some O(1) space merge sort solution, but I've never looked into it.

Comment: @roulette01 - O(1) space merge sort algorithms are mostly academic efforts these days. The code can be complex, as in this example which can work with or without a small buffer [grail merge sort github](https://github.com/Mrrl/GrailSort) . Take a look at GrailSort.h.

Comment: Buttom-up is often used in libraries, because the function call overhead in the recursive implementation is a significant cost.